# Dynamically adding to RouteTable isnt working

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am currently writing a news article aspect to an application and I adding the new route (for the new article) to my RouteTable, which appears to add fine, but the routes are unreachable?

The code I am using is as follows:

```
var routes = RouteTable.Routes;
using (routes.GetWriteLock())
{
    var url = contentHelper.GetPageUrl(page);
    routes.MapRoute(page.Id.ToString(), url, new { controller = "Cms", action = "Index", id = url }, new[] { "Web.Controllers.CmsController" });
}
```

The new Url, as I previously said, is added to the RouteTable.Routes but I cant get to the page. After a restart it is picked up by RegisterRoutes in the Global.asax and works fine.

Any light that you can shed on this would be great, as I want to achieve this without forcing an app restart

**EDIT**

This is the RegisterRoutes from my global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("LogOff", "LogOff", new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOff" });

        routes.MapRoute(
                "News", // Route name
                "News/",// URL with parameters
                new { controller = "NewsPage", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
                new[] { "Web.Controllers.NewsController" }
            );

        //register all content pages
        var urls = new ContentPageHelper().GetAllUrls();
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(url.Key.ToString(), url.Value, new { controller = "Cms", action = "Index", id = url.Key }, new[] { "Web.Controllers.CmsController" });
        }

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",// URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that calling  `RouteTable.MapRoute` adds the route to the end of the table.  Your default route is generally the last route to be added to the table, but since you are dynamically calling `RouteTable.MapRoute` after you have already built your route table, the default route is being hit before it reaches your newly added route.

My solution to this problem was as follows.

```
    public static void AddContentRoute(this RouteCollection routes, Data.UrlMap map, bool needsLock = false)
    {
        var route = new Route(map.Url, new MvcRouteHandler());
        route.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new
        {
            controller = "Content",
            action = "Display",
            id = map.Id,
            type = map.Type
        });

        if (needsLock)
        {
            using (routes.GetWriteLock())
            {
                routes.Insert(0, route);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            routes.Insert(0, route);
        }
    }
```

This essentially does what `RouteTable.MapRoute` does, but inserts the route to the top of the table instead of the end.

If you have other routes that need to sit at the top of the table you may want to modify this solution.

Comment: how do you determine if adding a route needs a lock or not (as you pass it as a parameter)?

Comment: The function I wrote was basically a copy of what RouteTable.MapRoute does (check the source and see for yourself). Use the lock in threaded situations, in most situations it won't be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you create a route on the fly? Wouldn't this defeat the purpose when the application does an app restart on it's own, all of those routes would need to be recreated for them to work

Why not create a route that just handles all of the request to your cms?

```
routes.MapRoute("CmsPage", "{page}", new { controller = "Cms", action = "Index"}, new [] { "Web.Controllers.CmsController" });
```

if you're doing it so it's not colliding with other routes/controllers in your applications, you could always prefix all cms generated pages with pages. I'm doing this for a CMS site that I'm creating now.

```
routes.MapRoute("CmsPage", "pages/{page}", new { controller = "Cms", action = "Index"}, new [] { "Web.Controllers.CmsController" });
```

Your action in your controller would be similar to this

```
public ActionResult Index(string page) 
{
    // logic to load page
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I am doing this already in global.asax, but I need the new pages as soon as they are made without having to restart the app

Comment: if the route is created in global.asax, they should already be available as soon as they're created. How are you retrieving your page when your Action is called? Do you store the page in the db?

Comment: Also adding 'Pages/' to the url is an ugly and hacky way of doing it, and it wont do anything positive from an SEO point of view.

See edit for global.asax